# Cannot run electron via "npm start" with X11 forwarding

Tags: npm, electron, x11-forwarding

Im trying to run an electron app over ssh with X11 forwarding on some headless machine. In that case just [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start). It works when I execute `electron .` in the cloned folder. But when I try to run it via `npm start`, which in turn execute that very same command, nothing happens. It doesn't even display an error message, it just silently ends:

```
electron-quick-start]$ npm start

> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start /home/codex/github/electron-quick-start
> electron .

electron-quick-start]$
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "npm start" method there is another system call on the lifecycle-cmd.js file.